# Partition rows based on order and data range

Tags: sql, sql-server

What kind of query would support taking into account both the order of my rows and a data range within them when ranking the row? The data should be processed in identity order and I want the range boundaries defines as `[Time] > 2 or [Time] < -2`.

Edit: In other words, I want to treat the rows as a list and break them into a list of lists where the ParitionId is the index of the list of rows.

Edit 2: I forgot to make it clear that the partition id should increment by one every time the [Time] value falls outside of the desired range. This requirement means we can't just bucket the rows using `GROUP BY` with a case statement returning true or false if [Time] falls inside the range or outside.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foobartable
    ([ID] int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL, [Time] float, [X] float, [Y] float)
;

INSERT INTO foobartable
    ([Time], [X], [Y])
VALUES
    (0.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (3.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (-1.0, 1, 1),
    (-2.0, 1, 1),
    (-3.0, 1, 1),
    (-2.0, 1, 1),
    (-1.0, 1, 1),
    (0.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (3.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1)
;
```

**Desired Results**

```
| Id | PartitionId |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |           0 |
|  2 |           0 |
|  3 |           0 |
|  4 |           1 |
|  5 |           2 |
|  6 |           2 |
|  7 |           2 |
|  8 |           2 |
|  9 |           3 |
| 10 |           4 |
| 11 |           4 |
| 12 |           4 |
| 13 |           4 |
| 14 |           4 |
| 15 |           5 |
| 16 |           6 |
```

Comment: You have obfuscated the real issue so much that I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SeanLange I want to assign a rank to a row based on it's order in a sequence of rows and based on the data within the row being either within or without a certain range. The desired results are just the row ids and the desired partition number. It's like breaking a list into a list of lists where the index of each list is the partition id.

Comment: What about when Time = 2 or Time = -2?
or do you mean [Time] >= 2 or [Time] <= -2

Comment: You explained the part about wanting partitions. What isn't clear to me is the rules about these partitions. Does it increase every time the next value goes below -2 or greater than 2? I am just not understanding the business rule here.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze The range is not inclusive of the values 2 and -2, so the range rule I have provided should be fine.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, the partition id does increment by 1 every time the value falls outside the range. Sorry for not being more clear on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, row_number() over(ORDER BY ID) rn
        FROM #foobartable 
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT cast(0 AS int) AS rn, NULL AS id,
        cast(NULL AS float) AS time,
        cast(NULL AS float) AS x,
        cast(NULL AS float) AS y,
        0 AS p
    UNION all
    SELECT cast(cte.rn AS int), cte.id,
        cte.[Time], cte.x, cte.y,
         iif(
                cte2.time <= 2.0 AND cte.time > 2.0 OR 
                cte2.time > 2.0 AND cte.time <= 2.0 OR 
                cte2.time >= -2.0 AND cte.time < -2.0 OR
                cte2.time < -2.0 AND cte.time >= -2.0
                ,p + 1
                ,p
            ) AS p
        FROM cte2
        JOIN cte ON cte2.rn + 1 = cte.rn
)
SELECT id, p AS PartitionId
    FROM cte2 
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY id;
```

Output:

```
id          PartitionId
----------- -----------
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           1
5           2
6           2
7           2
8           2
9           3
10          4
11          4
12          4
13          4
14          4
15          5
16          6
```

Comment: Excellent! This is pretty much the same thing I came up with. I wanted to see if anyone else knew of a different way to solve the problem using functions I might not have been aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c160/5)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foobartable
    ([ID] int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL, [Time] float, [X] float, [Y] float)
;

INSERT INTO foobartable
    ([Time], [X], [Y])
VALUES
    (0.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (3.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (-1.0, 1, 1),
    (-2.0, 1, 1),
    (-3.0, 1, 1),
    (-2.0, 1, 1),
    (-1.0, 1, 1),
    (0.0, 1, 1),
    (1.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1),
    (3.0, 1, 1),
    (2.0, 1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with pairs as (
  select
    t1.[ID] as [ID1],
    t2.[ID] as [ID2]
  from foobartable as t1
  left outer join foobartable as t2 on (t1.[ID] + 1) = t2.[ID]
),

loop ([ID], [Level])
as (
  select top 1
    t.[ID],
    0
  from foobartable as t
  union all
  select
    p.[ID2],
    (case when (case when t1.[Time] > 2 or t1.[Time] < -2 then 0 else 1 end) <> (case when t2.[Time] > 2 or t2.[Time] < -2 then 0 else 1 end) then [Level] + 1 else [Level] end) as [Level]
  from loop
  inner join pairs as p on p.[ID1] = loop.[ID]
  inner join foobartable as t1 on p.[ID1] = t1.[ID]
  inner join foobartable as t2 on p.[ID2] = t2.[ID]
 )

 select [Id], [Level] as [PartitionId] from loop
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c160/5/0)**:

```
| Id | PartitionId |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |           0 |
|  2 |           0 |
|  3 |           0 |
|  4 |           1 |
|  5 |           2 |
|  6 |           2 |
|  7 |           2 |
|  8 |           2 |
|  9 |           3 |
| 10 |           4 |
| 11 |           4 |
| 12 |           4 |
| 13 |           4 |
| 14 |           4 |
| 15 |           5 |
| 16 |           6 |
```